# java keylistener not working after export

Tags: java, applet, keylistener

I have a JFrame that hosts my Applet. There is a KeyListener on the applet to handle arrow keys and the enter/escape key.

When I run my JFrame in Eclipse, everything works fine, the arrow keys respond as well as the enter and escape key.

However, when I export my project to a Executable Jar file... the arrow keys still work, but the enter and escape key do not. How can I resolve this issue?

The code in the main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new SnakeApp().snake();
}

public void snake() throws Exception {
    // Set windows look
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");

    // Create window
    JFrame window = new JFrame("FinalSnake");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // Add FinalSnake applet
    FinalSnake finalSnake = new FinalSnake();
    finalSnake.init();
    finalSnake.start();
    window.add(finalSnake);

    // Set size
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(FinalSnake.GRIDSIZE * FinalSnake.GRIDX, FinalSnake.GRIDSIZE * FinalSnake.GRIDY));
    window.pack();

    // Set Icon
    window.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("gfx/icon.png")).getImage());

    // Center the frame
    Dimension frameSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    window.setLocation((frameSize.width - window.getSize().width) / 2, (frameSize.height - window.getSize().height) / 2);

    // Show the window
    window.setVisible(true);

    // And focus the FinalSnake applet
    finalSnake.requestFocusInWindow();
}
```

Code from the FinalSnake Applet:

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (this.world == null) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            this.gameType--;

            if (this.gameType == 0) {
                this.gameType = 2;
            }
        }

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            this.gameType++;

            if (this.gameType == 3) {
                this.gameType = 1;
            }
        }

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            this.world = new World(this.gameType);
        }
    } else {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
            this.world = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope someone can clear this out for me... Thnx

Comment: Why is `FinalSnake` an applet rather than a `JPanel`?  If it were a panel it could be added to an applet or application, and the focus problems would most likely disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`consume()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#consume%28%29) method on your `KeyEvent` variable. It says:

> Consumes this event so that it will
>   not be processed in the default manner
>   by the source which originated it.

This will override default manner I guess.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
//Do your actions
e.consume();
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the event isn't called at all for the enter and escape key, not that it gets handled too many times.

Comment: There was a question: [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053673/japplet-not-stopping-or-reacting-to-keyboard-input), and [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/155991), maybe this will help you get a clue.

Comment: Not really... my app works 100% while running through eclipse...

When I export it to an executable jar (for distribution) it doesn't work anymore...